# Create HTML form using rules defined in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

How do I create my HTML form based on rules I have in JSON ?

So I need to create a form like
[image]

My rules are in JSON as follows;

```
{
   "modules":[
      {
         "type":"navigation",
         "container":"#header",
         "title":"Top Navigation",
         "attributes":{
            "class":"topNavigation",
            "id":"topNavigation"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"content",
         "title":"Hi Welcome to mobile development",
         "subtitle":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
         "container":"#maincontent",
         "attributes":{
            "class":"topContent"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"form",
         "title":"Registration Form",
         "action":"submit.aspx",
         "name":"registrationform",
         "container":"#maincontent",
         "attributes":{
            "class":"registrationform"
         },
         "fields":[
            {
               "id":"firstname",
               "label":"First Name",
               "name":"fname",
               "type":"text",
               "value":""
            },
            {
               "id":"email",
               "label":"Email",
               "name":"email",
               "type":"text",
               "value":""
            },
            {
               "id":"countries",
               "label":"Country",
               "name":"countries",
               "type":"select",
               "options":[
                  {
                     "value":"",
                     "text":"Select Country"
                  },
                  {
                     "value":"in",
                     "text":"India",
                      "selected":"true"
                  },
                  {
                     "value":"us",
                     "text":"United Stated"

                  },
                  {
                     "value":"uk",
                     "text":"United Kingdom"
                  },
                  {
                     "value":"cn",
                     "text":"Canada"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"submit",
               "name":"submit",
               "type":"submit",
               "value":"Submit"
            }
         ],
         "rules":
            {
                "fname" : "required", 
                "email"     :   {
                                    "required": "true",
                                    "email": "true"
                                }
            },
         "messages":
            {
                "fname" : "Enter your firstname",
                "email" :   {
                                "required": "Please enter a valid email address",
                                "minlength": "Please enter a valid email address"
                            }
            }
      }
   ]
}
```

While I have used normal HTML/JS code to create such forms, I am not sure how to parse things/rules from JSON and then apply it to the HTML ?

I need to create the DOM for the HTML using JS as well...

Please provide me any similar references which I can have a look at.

Comment: I think it should be easier to map "type" attribute to existing html tag (form -> <form>) and map other attribute to related property of html tag (class:"test" -> class="test") , generate html string from JSON, and put the html string to a container.

Comment: Check out this [**JSON Form Builder**](http://ajaxian.com/archives/inputex-json-form-builder).

Comment: doing this from scratch is a ton of work to create all the different types of tags. Take a look at DForm plugin http://daffl.github.com/jquery.dform/

Comment: Well this is too much work with json.

Comment: and this seems like `interview with sapient nitro`

Comment: You're either looking for a library to accomplish this, or asking for us to write a program for you, neither of which is really appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Your key `type` is creating issues, `Question is` i tried it but not able to `find the third type` of form in `modules[]`. What you can do is `just put key to that type is form` similar to others.

Comment: @Jai : Can you provide something using modified json...

Comment: @testndtv plz wait for some while.

Comment: @Jai : Sure I'll wait...I'll appreciate whatever input you are able to provide..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/epk6Z/

for fiddle i used a variable `json`

```
$.each(json.modules, function (i, items) {
  $('<' + items.formElem + '/>').attr({
    "action": items.action,
        "name": items.name,
        "class": items.attributes.class
  }).appendTo('body');
  $('<h1/>').text(items.title).appendTo('.registrationform');
});
```

And in the ajax, this should be in the success function like this:

```
success: function(data){
 $.each(data.modules, function (i, items) {
  $('<' + items.formElem + '/>').attr({
    "action": items.action,
        "name": items.name,
        "class": items.attributes.class
  }).appendTo('body');
  $('<h1/>').text(items.title).appendTo('.registrationform');
 });
}
```

there are lot of other changes has to be made but this is just a shotest usage i did.

## json

```
{
"modules": [{
    "nav": "navigation",
        "container": "#header",
        "title": "Top Navigation",
        "attributes": {
        "class": "topNavigation",
            "id": "topNavigation"
    }
}, {
    "page-content": "content",
        "title": "Hi Welcome to mobile development",
        "subtitle": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
        "container": "#maincontent",
        "attributes": {
        "class": "topContent"
    }
}, {
    "formElem": "form", //<-----------i targeted this
        "title": "Registration Form",
        "action": "submit.aspx",
        "name": "registrationform",
        "container": "#maincontent",
        "attributes": {
        "class": "registrationform"
    }
    ...............
```

## note:

`Its not a full answer i just appended the form and the title of the form`

Comment: Thx a lot...Can you atleast add code to show one of the textboxes